# Live USB boots to black screen after grub menu on lg ultra book

Tags: boot, nvidia, lg

hi guys I really need help I tryed almost all linux distribution but with the same problem when I boot from usb and choose from grub Install ubuntu / try ubuntu I get black screen

I have a LG ultrabook 15UB470-K
Computer Specs:

```
CPU: Intel Core I7-6500U 2,50 GHz
Ram: 8Gb DDR4
Storage: SSD 250Gb
Graphics Card: Intel HD Graphics 520 + Nvidia Geforce 940MX
```

Fast boot & Secure boot are disabled
I tryed

```
nomodeset nolapci apci=off nouveau.modeset=0 nv.modeset=0 nvidia.modeset=0
```

but with no results

Please help me I really need Linux for Work & Study prupose

Note:

-When I tryed OpenSuse OS it freeze at "Loading intial ram-disk"

-When I tryed Minimal Linux OS (It is a project that only contains the linux kernel) it worked perfectly

Update:

-Linux Lite worked perfectly I think he is the only linux that worked for my computer, I don't know why other distribution like kali, manjaro, ubuntu, fedora, opensuse, deepin, elementary didn't work but linux lite worked

Could be that linux lite has some compatibility mode or some additional driver ??

Comment: Did you try a different USB? Not all flash drives work well in bootable state...

Comment: yeah I tryed diifferent USB and different USB creator tool I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, what I did is converting my disk from GPT to MBR using "EASEUS Partition Master" Software, and then booting any linux version worked perfectly

Comment: Please tell us which tool you use to flash the live system from the iso file to the USB drive.

Comment: I used balenaEtcher

Comment: Etcher is a cloning tool, and should be independent of the previous partition table. Is the problem with the {live drive / installer} or with the installed systems? You write 'tried' which indicates live drive, and 'disk' which indicates the internal drive and installed system. -- Anyway  it seems that the problem is that your computer 'does not want to boot' from a drive with GPT. But the problem could also be that the installers do not create a correct boot configuration, e.g. a missing `bios_grub` partition. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace),

Comment: Thanks for the info, what I meant is, I had windows installed in internal drive, and I flashed a usb in order to install linux (or just try live version) but when I boot to usb and after grub menu I just saw black screen

Comment: until I converted my internal drive from GPT partition to MBR

Comment: Thanks for sharing :-) So modifying the partition table of the internal drive made a difference also when you just tried a live version booting from an external drive! This is interesting new information for me. - Unless you also switched from secure boot, because that might prevent booting from USB.

Comment: when the problem happened, secure boot was disabled

Comment: So this is something new to me. Thanks again for these details :-)

Comment: no prob, anytime :-)